How to write an Includes type definition in typescript?
The requirement is to implement the JavaScript Array.includes function in the type system. A type takes the two arguments. The output should be a boolean true or false.
Below is my code snippet. The idea is to check each item of the array one by one and compare them with U, if the item equals U then return true otherwise return false.
type Includes<T extends any[], U> = 
T extends [infer First, ...infer Rest] 
?
  U extends First 
    ? First extends U ? true : Includes<Rest, U>
    : Includes<Rest, U>
: false;

type Test = Includes<[boolean, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7], false>; // returns true but should return false

I try to change the code snippet a little bit to better illustrate the issue.
type Includes<T extends any[], U> = 
T extends [infer First, ...infer Rest] 
?
  U extends First 
    ? First extends U ? number : string // from the result it returns number | string here; but First is boolean and U is false, so it should only return number right?
    : {name: string}
: false;
type Test = Includes<[boolean, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7], false>; // number | string; why?

Like i said in the above code comment,First is boolean, U is false, Why the final result type Test equals number | string? Could someone please help me explain the reason? Thanks a lot for your help.

• Your code snippet at the bottom is invalid TypeScript; please [edit] to fix syntax errors and make sure it is doing what you think it's doing. • You are using distributive conditional types unintentionally. You should turn off the distributive behavior as shown in this playground link. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer or find a duplicate source; if not, what's missing?

Thank you @jcalz I edited the code snippet and now the ts error are gone. When compare to my version, i saw you use [U] extends [First] ? [First] extends [U] ? true : Includes<Rest, U> : Includes<Rest, U>, in my case, i use U extends First      ? First extends U ? true : Includes<Rest, U> : Includes<Rest, U>, in your version the result is correct. But I am still confused why my code is not working....

Your code isn't working because you are accidentally using distributive conditional types. U extends First ? ⋯ : ⋯ ends up distributing the operation across unions in U, so if you evaluate it on a union like boolean, which is true | false, you get the true result unioned with the false result. If you want to treat unions as single things, you need to turn off distributivity, such as wrapping with [] (see "to avoid that behavior" in the doc linked above). See other q/a above.
